# Login script not working as required

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am new to php and tried to develop a login script but when i enter values it is not working. I cant even find the errors because when i click on submit it just refreshes the page

Here is my code

```
<?php include "../utilities/config.php"; 

foreach($_GET as $key=>$value)
{
${$key} = trim($value);
}
$error = '';
if($checking_member_availability == 'yes'){
if(empty($user_name)){
    $error .= "Please enter user name.<br />";
}
if(empty($password)){
    $error .= "Please enter password.<br />";
}
if(empty($error)){
        $sql = "select * from `".SITE_TABLE_PREFIX."user` where     email='".$user_name."' and pwd='".$password."'";
        $resultUser  = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error().$sql);
        if(mysql_num_rows($resultUser)>0){
        $rowUser  = mysql_fetch_array($resultUser);
        $error .= '';
        $_SESSION['email']=$user_name;
        }else{
        $error .= "Please check Email and Password.";
    }
}

if(empty($error)){

    echo "myaccount.php";
}
else{
    echo "<font color='#A01D49'>$error</font>";
}
}
?>
```

Please can anyone help me I have spent a lot of time without success

Here is the html code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function validation()
{
var password = trim(document.form1.password.value);
var user_name = trim(document.form1.user_name.value);
var type = trim(document.form1.type.value);
http.open("GET", "processor.php?checking_member_availability=yes&password="+
                    escape(password)+"&user_name="+   escape(user_name)+"&type=" + escape(type)  , true);
http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
http.send(null);
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<table width="241" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" <?php   if($_SESSION['user_id']!=''){?> style="display:none;"<?php }?>>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="loginBg">
                    <img src="img/logintxt.jpg" alt = '' width='100' height='29' border='0'>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="login"><form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return validation();">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                     <tr><td colspan="3"><span id="user"></span></td></tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="height"><label class="boldtxt">Email:</label></td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="heightMid"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle"><label class="boldtxt">Password:</label></td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="password" name="password" id='password' class="loginfld" />
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="image" src="img/submit.jpg" class="submit" onClick="return validation();" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="forget_password.php" class="normalTxt">Forgot your password?</a><br />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </form></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="provider_registration.php"><img src="images/applybut.jpg" alt="" border="0" class="apply" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="top">
                      <?=$value?>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that creates the form, too?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable for SQl injections. Check out PDO or mysqli and learn how to use prepared statements (not hard at all, but saves you a lot of trouble in the future!). And it looks like you rely on register_globals. Dont do that, just turn register_globals off.

Comment: We will need to see the html in order to help you.

Comment: As a side note, With your for loop blindly saving form values to internal variables, and your select statement piping those values in to your sql, you have left yourself open to a world of hurt.  Seriously, just pull out the $_GET values you need, specifically save them to variables and use mysql_real_escape_string to sanitize your inputs a bit.

Comment: thanks stephenbayer but I am really new to php, I have just build this code looking at few tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

ok, you have an echo statement with a file name:

```
   echo "myaccount.php";
```

First of all, are you sure that is what you want to do?  I believe that will echo the string "myaccount.php".  I believe you would want to include "myaccount.php"

secondly, you have referenced the form field "user_name" in your javascript, but the field name you are trying to access is named "email".  That might be part of the issue as well.

Comment: You also seem to be doing your validation in a complicated way, there are javascript libraries available like jQuery, which have already been written to do the asynchronous call you are trying to make.

Comment: I wanted to develop a login system with email as username and password. I searched on the net for few articles and out of that articles i developed this whisch is sort of login code. I am not able to correct the problem. It would be reallly great and I would be realy thankful if you can alter this code and make it run. I know i am asking lot fro yourll but I am really stressed out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using form `method="post"`, yet looking for `$_GET`.

Either use `method="get"` or `$_POST`!

As you have gathered from the comments there are several other issues with your code with regards to security. Don't be disheartened - everyone was a beginner once. However, you really should read up on [SQL Injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php) and stop assigning all the $_GET values to strings - name each of them in full, ie:

```
$user_name = trim($_GET['user_name']);
```

Good luck, and stick with it!

[edit]Ah, as Stephen rightly points out in the comments, the JS uses `get` to submit the post, so it's actually the field name of 'email' that's the problem.

Comment: the form is post, but the javascript passes it by GET, so isn't the issue I would believe, I think it has more to do with the "username" field being named "email", and then the javascript looking for the form name of "user_name"

Comment: Thanks grim. Can you help me in getting this fixed with sql injections like can u edit this code in the manner that login form is in working condition and no sql injection problem too. I am sorry i know i am asking for lot but I am really messed up with that

Comment: Hi Rajan - I'm happy to help but you should really create a new question so it will help other people in the future.

Comment: but what should be my new question like

Comment: Grim I asked a new question ad Working Login System. Can u pls now help me with this. thanks in advance